# Multiple definitions errors showed up in project history in 2020. Now no commit before that point can be built without adding "extern"

Tags: c, git, gitlab, extern, unresolved-external

A project I've been working on since 2000 compiled fine with brief periods of problems, maybe two or three commits at a time and very rare at that.  Back in February 2020, builds failed like this:

```
/usr/bin/ld: src/dumb/frotz_dumb.a(dinit.o):/home/foobar/src/dumb/dinit.c:26: multiple definition of `f_setup'; src/common/frotz_common.a(object.o):/home/foobar/src/common/object.c:23: first defined here
```

It was easily fixed by changing instances of `f_setup_t f_setup;` to `extern f_setup_t f_setup;` in the source files where the `f_setup` structure was accessed.  Simple, right?  But then I go back to 2011, when I finally started using Git for this project.  The compile fails pretty much the same way:

```
gcc -O2 -DCONFIG_DIR="\"/usr/local/etc\""  -DVERSION="\"2.43\"" -DSOUND_DEV="\"\"" -DCOLOR_SUPPORT      -o src/dumb/dumb_input.o -c src/dumb/dumb_input.c
src/dumb/dumb_input.c:82:13: error: conflicting types for ‘getline’
   82 | static void getline(char *s)
```

I set aside my frustrations with this in the past two years because, well, it builds and works fine now.  But now I'm working on an issue someone submitted along with two build logs: one from the latest commit and one from a commit before the easy fix I described above was committed.  So I tried a build on these older commits using a new user, then a fresh Debian machine, then a fresh FreeBSD machine.  I don't have a macOS machine, which is what the issue submitter is using.  This problem severely impacts my ability to do a bisect to root out trouble.

I really really REALLY don't want to insert fixes here and there starting in 2011 thereby making a mess of existing commit hashes.  My only guess as to what happened is some sort of default changed in GCC around 2020 for Debian.  So...  what the heck is going on?

The project I'm talking about is here: https://gitlab.com/DavidGriffith/frotz/.  The simple fix happened at https://gitlab.com/DavidGriffith/frotz/-/commit/b001e3f64a0f223136babb228f30fcac7fe09804

Comment: Back in DOS days, I worked for a software company that had a problem. Don't remember the version of DOS that _finally_ lifted the lid on number of concurrent open files. (DOS 3.0??) Manager was concerned about newest version of product that used lots of open files and how DOS 2.x clients couldn't run it... Turned out to be strong correlation between "old DOS" clients and "problem" clients... There comes a time (like saying good bye to Windows XP) that you have to draw a line and say, "2011 is over a decade ago." Evolution: "Adapt or perish..."

Comment: That comparison doesn't really line up with what's going on here.  For starters, trying to track down a bug that started sometime between 2019 and now is very important.

Comment: I'd not be surprised to find that the header files define variables and you are now using GCC 10 or later and running into the change in default from  `-fcommon` to `-fno-common`.  If it's your code, fix the headers so that they don't define variables (they are all prefixed with `extern` in the header), and ensure that one source file defines each declared variable.  If it's not your code, modify the build to include the `-fcommon` flag.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: In a sentence of the form “Fix the headers so they don’t do X (they all Y),” it is unclear whether Y is for doing X or Y is for not doing X.

Comment: @EricPostpischil — I mean that the fixed headers will not define any variables because every variable declaration is prefixed with `extern` (and does not include any initializer).  However, every variable that's used must be defined in a source file — but different variables may be defined in different source files.

Comment: Bugs like this are almost always caused by defining variables or functions in header files. This in turn could cause all manner of linker-related problems. Get rid of such definitions from header files and also ensure that all headers have header guards. As for `getline` specifically, there is a POSIX function with the same name that the non-conforming gcc compiler will add to `stdio.h` to break your conforming program. In order to prevent that, use gcc in conforming C compiler mode `-std=c17 -pedantic-errors`.

Comment: "I don't have a macOS machine, which is what the issue submitter is using." Maybe they were using clang instead of gcc? I don't think clang has the same tendency as gcc to spew non-reserved identifiers into standard headers.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I know what you meant; whether a particular form of declaration will define an object is not the point of my comment. The point is that sentence structure does not convey, in a deterministic way, information to a reader who does not already know. In the English sentence “The city council denied the applicants a permit to protest because they were afraid of rioting,” “they” refers to the city council, who is afraid of rioting during the protest. In “The city council denied the appilcants a permit to protest because they were afraid of war,” they refers to the applicants,…

Comment: … who are afraid of war. Those sentences are nearly identical; they differ in a single word, of which both choices refer to multiple people committing violent acts. In “fix the headers so that they don't define variables (they are all prefixed with extern in the header),” it is not clear whether the parenthesized phrase is telling the reader about defining variables or about not defining variables. My point is that, when seeking to convey information to a person who does not already know it, one needs to be clear in the phrasing.

Comment: @Lundin: [The standard library headers beyond those required for freestanding implementations are separate from GCC and Clang](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Standard-Libraries.html#Standard-Libraries), although they are often distributed with them. Neither Clang nor GCC is to blame for non-standard identifiers introduced by `<stdio.h>`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil By gcc etc I mean "the implementation"; that is the compiler + standard libs. And gcc and clang may not necessarily be using the same lib on the same target.

Comment: @Lundin: By “GCC” I mean GCC. I find words work better that way.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It is up to those who make the specific gcc port to decide which lib to use. So it is still "gcc" even though the core compiler doesn't come with libs.

Comment: The [`git bisect` examples](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect#_examples) contain an example for how to check with a temporary hot-fix, which you can also do manually (and doesn't have to dirty your existing commits)

Comment: @lundin I also tried CLANG.  There was no improvement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C standard does not define the behavior of using `f_setup_t f_setup;` in multiple translation units. This form of declaration is called a *tentative definition*, although it is not actually a definition. However, it causes a definition to be created if no definition is seen before the end of a translation unit.

Due to the history of C development, this form of declaration was handled differently by different C implementations. It was a documented Unix behavior that definitions created by tentative definitions created “common” symbols were coalesced during linking (multiple instances of the same “common” symbol would be linked into references to a single entity). So uses of these declarations in header files would work without causing linker errors. In other C implementations, tentative definitions would create hard references that would cause linker errors about multiple definitions. Because different C implementations treated them differently, the C standard did not require one behavior or another; it left it undefined.

Prior to GCC version 10, GCC marked tentative definitions as “common” symbols by default. The default changed in GCC version 10.

To remedy the issue, you can use a GCC version earlier than version 10, you can add `-fcommon` to your compile commands to select the old behavior, or you can add `extern` to the declarations to make them into ordinary declarations that are not definitions instead of tentative definitions. In the latter case, you will need to ensure there is exactly one definition of the identifier somewhere in the program.

Comment: This seems to neatly explain the problem.  I'll follow @Hasturkun's suggestion for using `git bisect`'s scripting functionality to get my bisect testing done.